# Does the deploy destroy data?

Tags: newmips

I have a deployed newMips app and did put some data in.

I need to change a field (add a value to an enum). As far as I understood, I have to ask Mipsy to redeploy the app. Will she drop the current data or is she intelligent enough to keep it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current release 2.3 (fix 2.3.0.2), when you change the structure of an entity, the deploy function will not change the structure if data values already exist in your entity.

The database synchronization will be entirely made available in the next release 2.4 (planned October 2017).

It will be working this way for enum values :

- If the current values of your data field (in the production environment) equal the enum values, then the values will be kept
- Otherwise, the values will be dropped.